# How to load an XHTML page into a dialog in primefaces only when the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need to load an XHTML page inside a dialog in prime-faces when the button is pressed, what i tried so far loads the page immediately inside the main XHTML that i could show using view source in the browser, i just need to load it only in button press.

Things I've tried:

```
<p:commandButton value="Learn More" style="float:right;"
onclick="helpDialogVar.show(); return false;" />

<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Learn More"
    widgetVar="helpDialogVar" height="300" width="500" resizable="false"
    position="right" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" draggable="true"
>
<ui:include src="page_to_load_inside_dialog.xhtml"    
        </p:dialog>
```

Also using iframe:

```
  <p:commandButton value="Learn More" style="float:right;"
       onclick="helpDialogVar.show(); return false;" />

 <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Learn More"
    widgetVar="helpDialogVar" height="300" width="500" resizable="false"
    position="right" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" draggable="true"
    onHide="jQuery('#someId').hide();" onShow="jQuery('#someId').show();">
    <h:form prependId="false">
    <h:outputFormat escape="false">
    <iframe frameborder="0" align="left" src="page_to_load_inside_dialog.xhtml"
    name="someName" id="someId" scrolling="auto" width="750"
    height="500" marginheight="5" marginwidth="10">
</iframe>
    </h:outputFormat>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `dynamic="true"` attribute on the dialog.

---

Ideally, you should be launching the dialog using primefaces' [Dialog Framework](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml)